# NodeJS abstract service for handling Dynamodb and Cassandra

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, swagger

So currently we are using amazon dynamodb in our project.
But we want eventually to replace it with Cassandra( as we need it in order to have box solution )

Is it possible to write some abstraction service which will be easily reconfigure for using Cassandra in future?

We are using nodejs express framework for building backend micro-services.